# Quantifying error on georeferenced aerial imagery

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, aerial-photography

I georeferenced historical aerial imagery of a coastal area to estimate the size of oil sheens on the surface of the ocean. The control points I used were on land (street intersections, buildings, etc.), and I used thin plate spline interpolation. I don't know much about it besides what I learned from this [page](https://profs.etsmtl.ca/hlombaert/thinplates/).

Is there any way I can quantify the error on the size of the oil sheens?